# How to use multiple local images properly in Next.js 13 component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a Next.js app and I'm using the Image component to display images. I know how to import a single local image like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import profilePic from '../public/me.png';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Image
      src={profilePic}
      alt="Picture of the author"
    />
  );
}
```

But I have a section on my page where I want to display multiple partner company logo images. Currently, I'm importing each image individually like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image'; 
import comanylogo1 from '../public/companies/comanylogo1.png'; 
import comanylogo2 from '../public/companies/comanylogo2.png';
 ... 
import comanylogo15 from '../public/companies/comanylogo15.png';
```

Then I'm manually rendering each logo using the Image component. This works, but I think, it's not efficient.
I'm looking for a better way to import and render multiple local images using the Image component.

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this in Next.js?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since they are in the public folder, you are not obligated to import them. I think you could do `src="/me.png"`.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your images path as an array

```
export const CompanyLogosImgSrc: string[] = [
  "../public/companies/comanylogo1.png",
  "../public/companies/comanylogo2.png",
  "../public/companies/comanylogo3.png",
  "../public/companies/comanylogo4.png",
];
```

Import it and use `map` to loop it

```
import { CompanyLogosImgSrc } from "your_path/CompanyLogosImgSrc"
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Page() {
  return CompanyLogosImgSrc.map((src) => (
    <Image key={src} src={src} alt="Picture of the author" />
  ));
}
```